# how to populate the column in DB sql-server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How would i get substring of file name

i want to extract date from filename and populate mydatekey column which is in my table ?

example :  `subfolder_21-03-2009.txt`

i want to extract `21-03-2009` and populate the column in my Database !

using `SSIS` tasks

So on successful execution there will be column with the date extracted .

```
column
21-03-2009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A derived column in between Flat file and oledb destination should do the job

[image]

Comment: whoa... tht expression works with little changes man thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If it is a directory of files. Use a `ForEach Loop` container to enumerate all your files in the directory.  Next you need to put a `Data Flow Task` in your `ForEach Loop` Container.  Within the `Data Flow Task` you need to add a `Flat File source`. Then you need to add a `Derived Column` transformation after your `Flat File source`.  Within your `Derived Column` you need to add the variable that you used to loop through the directory into the "Derived Column Name"; in the "Derived Column" put "Add as new column", and in the "Expression" you would use a `FindString` expression or a combination of `LEFT/RIGHT` expressions to grab the date from the file name.  Then in your `OLE DB Destination` object you need to map your derived column to the relative column in your SQL-Server DB.

FINDSTRING:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx

LEFT/RIGHT:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231081.aspx

Comment: To add to Jeff's answer... assume your filename is in a package-level variable called "filename."  The expression in your derived column transform would look like this:  (DT_STR,10,1252)SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::filename],14),1,10)